# Аnimate по условию, синтаксический вопрос

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу сделать анимированную шапку сайта. Чтобы при прокрутке страницы вниз шапка на заданное количество пикселей "уезжала" вверх, а при возвращении страницы в исходную позицию шапка возвращалась обратно.

Для наглядности напишу вопрос в коде

```js
jQuery(function(f) {
  var element = f('#header2');
  f(window).scroll(function() {
    //Вот так все правильно работает, но это не тот эффект, который мне нужен
    //element['fade'+ (f(this).scrollTop() > 10 ? 'Out': 'In')](500);

    //Пытаюсь как-то так, но не могу параметры смещения завернуть в условие
    //В исходную позицию шапка, конечно, не возвращается. Помогите с синтаксисом
    //element['animate'+ (f(this).scrollTop() > 10 ? '': '')]({top:"-30"},200);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header2" style="height:100px;border:solid red 1px;position:fixed;background-color:#fff;">HEADER</div>

<div style="position: absolute; height:3000px;">BODY</div>
```

Comment: а какую строку ты хочешь собрать? в первом случае ты получаешь либо fade in, либо fade out, А во втором что хочешь получить?

Comment: Вторую строку. То что в первой строке просто собираются названия функций это понятно. А я хочу чтобы выполнялась animate с разными параметрами по условию scrollTop() > 10

Comment: не, я имел ввиду: как должна выглядеть новая строка?

Comment: В том то и дело, что я не знаю, совершенно не понимаю синтаксис. Сейчас постараюсь понятней. В первом варианте, где fade in и out при прокрутке страницы вниз блок исчезает, а при прокрутке вверх появляется, но мне нужна другая анимация, при помощи animate. Чтобы блок уезжал вверх и возвращался вниз. Но с animate вариант как с fade не пройдет. Там надо не просто тупо изменить название функции, а присваивать параметры (стили) при прокрутки. Вот я и не знаю как это зделать.

Comment: Тоесть что-то типа if(скрол > 10px) {animate({top:"-30"},200)} else {animate({top:"0"},200)}

Comment: чем не устраивает именно такая строка? :-) зачем пытаться все в одну строку впихнуть?

Comment: по сути, раз от условия зависит только значение _top_ то и надо только его устанавливать: `{top:scrollTop() > 10?"-30":"0"}`

Comment: Эх, если бы я мог ее не словами написать, конечно бы устроила. У меня врожденная неспособность понять js. Уже час сижу последнюю подсказку то туда то сюда пытаюсь влепить, ничего не получается.

Comment: :-D это потому что перед scrollTop забыл `f(this).`

Comment: Попробовал так animate({top:(f(this).scrollTop() > 10) ? "-30px" : "60px"},200); и еще множество вариантов, ничего не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function(f){
var element = f('#head');
f(window).scroll(function(){
element.stop().animate({top:f(this).scrollTop() > 5 ? '-50px' : '0px'}, 80);                
});
});
```